# How can I soft reset?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I've already completed the game 3 times and I only recently found out about Soft Resetting. I wanted to try it but after 17 on Heatran, I got really Impatient.

If anyone has an easily explained tutorial on how to soft reset and how to **automate** this, please tell me because I'm itching to get a shiny legendary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'Soft-Resetting' just means restarting the game without quitting out first.

- Save in front of the legendary Pokemon
- Start the battle
- If it's not shiny, press and hold <kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and press either <kbd>Select</kbd> or <kbd>Start</kbd> to perform a soft-reset.
- The screen will go black and the game will start loading the title screen.

#### Notes

- Some legenaries are still shiny-locked (At this stage believed to be only Groudon, Kyogre, and Rayquaza), therefore you cannot get them Shiny.
- The [chance of encountering a shiny](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Pok%C3%A9mon#Generation_VI) is really low, and no different between regular wild Pokemon and legendaries.

  - It's a 16/65536 (1/4096) chance of finding one, or 0.0244%.

---

In response to your edit:

What you are effectively doing by soft resetting is dice-rolling until you get a certain number, except in this case the dice has 4096 sides.

To automate the process you would need everything from a program that can tell whether a Pokemon is shiny, to somehow automatically pushing the buttons (using robotics or directly soldering your 3DS). Needless to say, automation is not really an option unless you're willing to do some heavy modification to your 3DS. See [BlueRaja's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/196551/28182) for options to do so

If you are adamant about saving time, you could change the Pokemon to be shiny *after* its caught using a Powersave/Action Replay device. Do note that this is directly cheating and generally frowned upon by the wider community (so is soft-resetting according to some purists but it's less frowned upon than Powersave).

Comment: Deoxys is shiny locked, not Giratina.

Comment: @pinckerman found [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/ShinyPokemon/comments/2nfc3s/all_half_confirmed_srable_legends_in_oras/) to confirm Giratina is resettable, however it lists Deoxys as 'unknown'. Do you have a source?

Comment: Not 100% confirmed, but [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/games/shiny.shtml) lists him under shiny-locked.

Comment: @pinckerman - cool :)

Comment: All legendaries relevant to the story are shiny locked and the rest are not.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is possible to automate the process.  However, it involves taking apart your 3DS and requires quite a bit of hardware knowledge, and so is not for the faint of heart.

[Here](http://technabob.com/blog/2014/01/02/pokemon-xy-automatic-egg-hatcher-shiny-finder/) is a link to the original "automatic shiny finder," and [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/1rjbz9/successfully_recreated_the_automatic_shiny/) is a link to someone who was able to successfully recreate it.  [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9rO9NdW49o) is a link to a different one, which uses a similar method to achieve the same result.

Comment: Awesome! I couldn't find anything when I searched :). I've removed the part from my answer which says you can't, and pointed to yours for how to do it :)

Comment: Ok, because I think im a bit too young to work with the _taking apart_ process, so I think I might rather use Dexnav.