# Can't seem to soft reset in Pokemon?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Whenever I try to soft reset holding <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Select</kbd> or <kbd>Start</kbd> nothing happens. Do I have to do something to my DS or something?

I have the most recent update for Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I soft reset?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/196428/how-can-i-soft-reset)

Comment: You can always just press Home and close the game.

Comment: @Unionhawk - sounds more like a broken button than a problem with not knowing how to soft reset

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are **holding** <kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> when you push <kbd>Select</kbd> or <kbd>Start</kbd>.

It's more than likely that one of your bumper buttons are broken. A hard knock such as dropping your 3DS would be enough to break the buttons.

You can test if it's the buttons by running a simple test:

Exit the Pokemon Game, and whilst on the Home menu, alternate between pressing <kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> - you should see each button light up the outlines in the bottom right of the top screen (The place where it says holding both should launch the camera). If one doesn't light up, you know it's that button which is broken.

Comment: Ya but what about the select and start keys. Huh?

Comment: @Aaron - if you can't push Start, you'll be unable to return to the homescreen from within an app

Comment: Are there Any alternatives when the R button is broken?

Comment: @Derp not that I'm aware of, but if it *IS* broken you could take it to an electronics repair shop, chances are they could fix it relatively easily/cheaply.